# How do I resolve RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'?

Tags: python, heroku, runtime-error, nltk, dashboard

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
-----> Downloading NLTK packages: wordnet
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
 warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to /tmp/build_258085236d56e3b4
[nltk_data]     5c3f16d4bfeb1865/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
 [nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/wordnet.zip.

.....
   Released v8

   https://cov-19dashboard.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

While trying to deploy an app on Heroku I keep getting this Runtime error.

I've tried replacing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

on the main app file (app.py) with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import warnings
    warnings.warn("use 'python -m nltk', not 'python -m nltk.downloader'",         DeprecationWarning)
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

but I still get the warning, which is preventing the dash app from displaying correctly on the Heroku server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem that failed the deploy process may be not the warnings that you mentioned above. To see exactly what are the failed steps encountered during the deploy process you must investigate the log file by tapping `$ heroku logs --tail` on your terminal.
About the nltk package, if you used windows to edit your app files, ensuring that the `nltk.txt` file is converted to unix endings in order to successufly downloading that you needed. As example, you need to download `stopwords` and `punkt` packages, edit the `nltk.txt` file like this:

`stopwords`

`punkt`

The most important thing is to successufly investigating the logs using the command `heroku logs` from your terminal and not only reading the Build Log from the heroku dashboard. This latter doesn't give you the root cause of the failing deployment.

Comment: ``nltk.txt`` file should containing one line for each package.

Comment: The heroku log does not actually mention anything helpful.
That is b/c this is a RunTime issue, not a Build Time issue I suppose.